# Getting Illegal instruction: illegal hardware instruction python manage.py runserver on Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, django, macos, apple-m1

I am trying to bring up a Django project with the below dep:

python 3.6 and django>2.0

All dependencies have been successfully installed but when I try to bring the server up it gives me the below error and exit after that:

> [1]    3298 illegal hardware instruction  python manage.py runserver

I am using MacOS Big Sur 11.2.2 with Apple M1 chip.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: I get the above error when I execute the commond :
`python manage.py runserver`

No traceback available as the error is outputted just after running the runserver.

Comment: Take a look at [osx port install of php74 crashes with Illegal instruction: 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414346/325300), it's somewhat related.

Comment: @LordElrond thanks for help but this might not help as this is somewhat related to memory issue. Mine is specifically related to M1 chip as when I am running the command with python3.8 everything is up and running except I am facing issues with project specific dep as project requires python3.6.

Comment: Did you try to debug through the code of django itself as it does the runserver? If you go line by line, you will eventually find the line that is probably doing some low level call that is not supported on Mac M1.

Answer (score -1):

pip install --no-binary psycopg2 pyscopg2